# WinRM fails: The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request

Tags: powershell, winrm

I have two servers (sourceserver1 and destinationserver1). They are not on the same network segment, but do have connectivity. Today, Invoke-Command stopped working when sourceserver1 tries to connect to destinationserver1 and I am not sure why. PowerShell shows the error:

> [<destinationserver1's IPv4>] Connecting to remote server
> <destinationserver1's IPv4> failed with the following error message :
> The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.
> Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting
> requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management
> service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the
> destination is the WinRM service, run the  following command on the
> destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm
> quickconfig". For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

On destinationserver1, I checked:

- Ran: winrm quickconfig
- Result: WinRM already configured
- Ran: Get-WSManInstance winrm/config/listener -Enumerate
- Result:

  cfg                   : http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/config/listener

  xsi                   : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

  lang                  : en-US

  Address               : *

  Transport             : HTTP

  Port                  : 5985

  Hostname              :

  Enabled               : true

  URLPrefix             : wsman

  CertificateThumbprint :

  ListeningOn           : {127.0.0.1, <destinationserver1's IPv4>, ::1, <destinationserver1's IPv6>}
- Ran: winrm get winrm/config
- Result: No IPv4 or IPv6 filters
- Ran: netstat -aon | find "5985"
- Result:

  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57526    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57544    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    <destinationserver1's IPv4>:5985       <sourceserver1's IPv4>:57585    ESTABLISHED     4

  TCP    [::]:5985              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4

On sourceserver1, I checked:

- Ran: (get-Item wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts).value
- Result: found the IP of destinationserver1, which is how I am trying to connect
- Ran: telnet <destinationserver1's IPv4> 5985
- Result: the connection was successful
- Ran: Test-NetConnection <destinationserver1's IPv4> -port 5985
- Result:

  ComputerName           : <destinationserver1's IPv4>

  RemoteAddress          : <destinationserver1's IPv4>

  RemotePort             : 5985

  InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet

  SourceAddress          : <sourceserver1's IPv4>

  PingSucceeded          : True

  PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 0 ms

  TcpTestSucceeded       : True

Other connectivity, like "ping" works, in both directions.

Not sure what else to check.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I've tried everything but nothing has worked.

Comment: No, not that I recall.